# Features (Attributes) ranking

Tags: machine-learning, weka, feature-selection

I have a dataset with items and features (attributes). Each item has some features.

Total number of features ~400 feature.

I want to rank the features based on their importance. I am not looking for classification, I am looking for features ranking.

I convert the item-feature into a binary matrix like the fowllowing, where 1 means this feature exists in this item and 0 otherwise.

`itemID | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 | feature4 ....
  1     |    0     |    1     |    1     |    0 
  2     |    1     |    0     |    0     |    1
  3     |    1     |    1     |    1     |    0
  4     |    0     |    0     |    1     |    1`

An example of real data is for hotels, where features could be something like: Air Condition, Free WiFi, etc.

`HotelID | Air Condition| Free WiFi ....
  1      |    0         |    1
  2      |    1         |    0
  3      |    1         |    1
  4      |    0         |    0
.....`

I need to know what to use and how to use it.

A sample code will be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for an algorithm such as [Information Gain](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/attributeSelection/InfoGainAttributeEval.html).
Taken from the documentation of the class:

> Evaluates the worth of an attribute by measuring the information gain
>   with respect to the class

Here you can find a usage example:

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=weka.attributeSelection.InfoGainAttributeEval

Good luck.